# Kendo UI, Asp.net Modal click event

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui

I am doing a project where I have this button inside a grid view,and need the modal to pop up with data inside of it, I saw a similar post on here but they were not using Asp.net-mvc(4.5). 
I know the button works, I used a `alert()` to test it, but when I put this in I get an error

> "Index:144 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'content' of null"

Which is referring to wnd. `Content(detailsTemplate(dataItem))`. Please lend me your thoughts.

```
@(
    Html.Kendo().Grid<PartsViewModel>().Name("serializes")
.Columns(columns   =>
    {
        columns.Bound(parts => parts.PartNumber).Width(40);
        columns.Bound(parts => parts.DrawingNumber).Width(40);
        columns.Bound(parts => parts.SupplierName).Width(40);
        columns.Bound(parts => parts.SupplierNumber).Width(40);
        columns.Bound(parts => parts.Description).Width(40);
        columns
.Command(command =>  command.Custom("ViewDetails")
.Click("showDetails")).Width(15);
    })
    .Pageable(Settings.Telerik.Grid.Pageable)
    .Sortable(Settings.Telerik.Grid.Sortable)
    .Reorderable(Settings.Telerik.Grid.Reorderable)
    .Resizable(Settings.Telerik.Grid.Resizable)
    .Scrollable(Settings.Telerik.Grid.Scrollable)
    .Filterable(Settings.Telerik.Grid.Filterable)
    .ColumnMenu(Settings.Telerik.Grid.ColumnMenu)
    .DataSource(datasource => datasource.Ajax()
        .Events(events => events.Error("error_handler"))
        .PageSize(Settings.Telerik.Grid.Pages.PageSize).Model(model =>
        {
            model.Id(partSearch => partSearch.PartId);
            model.Field(partSearch => partSearch.PartNumber);
            model.Field(partSearch => partSearch.DrawingNumber);
            model.Field(partSearch => partSearch.SupplierName);
            model.Field(partSearch => partSearch.RevisionNumber);
            model.Field(partSearch => partSearch.RevisionDescription);
            model.Field(partSearch => partSearch.RevisionDate);
            model.Field(partSearch => partSearch.ShortDescription);
            model.Field(partSearch => partSearch.ShortDescription);
            model.Field(partSearch => partSearch.PurchasingComments);
            model.Field(partSearch => partSearch.ManufacturingComments);
            model.Field(partSearch => partSearch.EngineeringComments);
            model.Field(partSearch => partSearch.Description);
        })
        .Read(read => read.Action("ReadPartSearch", "PartsSearch"))
        /*.Create(update => update.Action("CreateParts", "Search"))*/)
)

@section scripts{
<script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="template">
    <div id="details-container">
        <h2>#= Created # #= LastName #</h2>
        <em>#= Title #</em>
        <dl>
            <dt>City: #= City #</dt>
            <dt>Address: #= Address #</dt>
        </dl>
    </div>
 </script>

 <script>     
    var detailsTemplate = kendo.template($("#template").html());

    function showDetails(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var dataItem = this.dataItem($(e.currentTarget).closest("tr"));

        var wnd = $("#Details").kendoWindow({
            title: "Details",
            content: "Created",
            modal: true,
            visible: false,
            resizable: false,
            width: 300
        }).data("kendoWindow");
        detailsTemplate = kendo.template($("#template").html());

        wnd.content(detailsTemplate(dataItem));
        wnd.center().open();
    }

    function error_handler(args) {
        searcher.kendoGrid.errorHandler($("#serializes"), args);
    };

    function clearFilter(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var grid = $("#serializes").data("kendoGrid");
        grid.dataSource.filter({});
    };
    $(function () {
        //searcher.kendoGrid.initClearButton($("#serializes"), clearFilter);
        searcher.kendoGrid.autoResize($('#serializes'), getSubtractors());
    });
</script>
}
```

Comment: dataItem = i {_events: Object, _handlers: Object, PartId: 16773, PartNumber: "70706", ShortDescription: "FILTER"…}, e = i.Event {originalEvent: MouseEvent, type: "click", timeStamp: 50880.9, jQuery1102026239493182004714: true, toElement: a.k-button.k-button-icontext.k-grid-ViewDetails…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"#Details" is not defined in the code, ergo content is null.